# Secure Python chat with SSH - How?

Tags: python, security, ssh, network-programming, chat

I am trying to create a secure chat server with python, and after many hours of hunting all I have discovered is that I should use SSH, and that Paramiko seems to be the best python module for it (I may be wrong). I cannot find out how to implement this though, and being quite new to Python, the docs were a bit deep for me, especially as I didn't really know what to look for!

Any links to example code would be greatly appreciated, especially concerning the server (there seems to be hundreds of examples about connecting to an ssh server, but none about creating them - am i missing something vital here? I have heard that it is possible to create an ssh server in python, but the apparent lack of code on the internet is worrying me)

Thanks

EDIT:

My ultimate goal is to create a secure chat client with python, and I would like to keep it as simple as possible, however, security is the main goal. I have seen and made several chat clients in the recent past, however, they required telnet to connect to them, so were not secure, I wish to correct this.

Comment: There are a variety of solutions available for securing connections between your participants; a little bit more research may be in order before you settle on ssh as your transport for this purpose.

Comment: Perhaps you should learn a little python before embarking on a SSH server code. That said, there are some [examples in Paramiko's github page](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos), and one for an [ssh server](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_server.py)

Comment: @SalvadorDali I have seen many examples of generic chat applications with python and appreciate your comment, but my main goal here is to make a _secure_ chat application

Comment: SSH is only likely to be the right answer if you're trying to do something like tunnel an talk/ntalk/ytalk-type connection between machines where both users have accounts on both machines. The whole point of SSH is that you're using your own credentials on the remove machine for authentication. You probably wanted SSL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/), an asynchronous networking engine written in Python. They have a very simple example called [`chatserver.py`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/index.html). Get that running and then make it [listen on SSL](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html) using a [self-signed SSL certificate](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html).

Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054177/twisted-number-of-client-connections-to-tcp-server-limited).

Comment: Good luck! Please let report back to us to let us know how it goes!!